# Will I recieve notifications on my device if I do FirebaseDatabase.goOffline()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

In my code, I have a function like

```
takeDatabasesOffline()
{
   FirebaseDatabase.goOffline();
   FirebaseFirestore.disableNetwork();
}
```

My question is if I do such a thing, will the notifications (from firebaseCloudMessaging) stop coming?

If so, how can I ensure notifications continue coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should continue to receive messages even if you set the databases to offline. Firebase Cloud Messaging message delivery is independent of Realtime Database and Firestore.